# How to combine x-axis labels in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/3347zfgw/

```
 Code block to make SO happy
```

In the above jsfiddle i have a line chart showing the number of events in a given month spanning multiple years. In this situation I'd like to have a label for each year and not each nothing. You can imagine what this looks like when i do the same thing at a day level. In that case i want to show labels for the month.

Id like to see this jsfiddle updated with the approach.

Additional information: 
- This is a config that is programatically generated. I did clean it up to keep it a little simpler for the question. I left enough to see the context we are working in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first and foremost recommend using a `datetime` x axis type, since you are displaying time series data.

The chart will then automatically use a logical interval, and if you don't like the one it picks you can specify it with the `tickInterval` property.

Using categories tells the chart to make a label for each by default, and just doesn't make sense for a time series anyway.

However, while using categories on the x axis, you can still use the tickInterval property to achieve what you need here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3347zfgw/1/

Comment: I apologize for not accepting this answer previously, I thought i had. I am going to accept this answer now. Thank you.